# Como capturar objeto File enviado con fetch en un Controlador de Symfony

Tags: reactjs, symfony, fetch

Tengo el siguiente código donde envió asicronicamente un objeto file..
Esta es la funcion con que capturo el objeto File

```
handleChangeAudio: (event) => {
            var arrayAudio = event.target.files;
            function readerFiles(files){
                let fileRead = null
                 for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                 var reader = new FileReader();  
                 reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                      return function(e) {
                        dispatch(uploadAudioBackend(e.target.result))
                      };
                    })(f);

                    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
                  reader.readAsDataURL(f);
               }  
              }
```

Esta es la función fetch con la que llamo al controlador de Symfony y le envio los datos..

```
return fetch('/api/upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({arrayAudio:arrayAudio})
        })
```

Este es el controlador de Symfony con el que capturo los datos enviados desde el cliente..

```
/**
     * @Route("/api/upload", name="api_upload")
     */
    public function apiUploadAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $contentAudioUpload = $request->getContent();
        $parametersAsArrayAudio = json_decode($contentAudioUpload);

        $arrayAudioUploads = $parametersAsArrayAudio->{'arrayAudio'};

        $filename = uniqid().".".$arrayAudioUploads->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $serializer = $this->get('serializer');
        return new JsonResponse($serializer->normalize(1) );
    }
```

y me da el siguiente error...

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cosas que creo que están mal.

Cuando usas fetch para enviar un archivo a un API tienes quitar el content-type porque claramente no es un json, luego el browser se encarga de ponerle el correcto y ademas en el body de la petición tiene que venir el archivo.

Yo creo que no lo ves es porque ni se llega a enviar bien.

**Edit:**

Encontré un ejemplo de eso:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067767/how-do-i-upload-a-file-with-the-js-fetch-api